# Do all server guest accounts have emulated operating systems?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, server, hypervisor

If a physical server is running a particular operating system and a hypervisor on top, do all guest accounts have the same operating system as that server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypervisor guests run their own operating systems.

Depending on how the hypervisor is implemented (you mention in your question that it runs "on top of" a particular host operating system) parts of what that guest sees as "hardware" may actually be emulated/wrapped by the host OS, but software running on the guest will not be aware of that (it only sees its own guest OS).